# How to select different values in different dates in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to get the number of customers that a company had each day for the last 7 days. But when I run my code I get the total of customers for the week and is just displaying the last order date.

```
SELECT order_date, COUNT(DISTINCT buyerid) as 'customers' from orders
WHERE
date(order_date) >= curdate() - 7
AND date(order_date) <= curdate()
```

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot make use of an image of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: I edited out the image. Thanks

Comment: Please specify the database product you are using (SQLServer, Oracle, MySQl, etc..)
Shouldn't your last criteria `AND date(order_date) = curdate()` be <= (instead of =)?

Comment: Its displaying the same results with '<='

Comment: I've already posted an answer but if it doesn't work, please run `show create table orders` and post it in your question along with some dummy data so I can reproduce it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is able to run because it's not in 'full group by only' mode. That is because you're not aggregating the order_date, so you end up displaying only the last date and counting all the buyerids. This is almost never an expected result, I might say.

I would rewrite it like so:

```
SELECT order_date, COUNT(DISTINCT buyerid) as 'customers'
FROM orders
WHERE
    order_date >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 week)
GROUP BY order_date
```

Now it will count the distinct buyerids in each day.

Also, `curdate() - 7` doesn't seem to work so I rewrote it entirely, assuming order_date is of date type.

Mind you might miss results if its a datetime, and in that case compare it to `now()` or strip time entirely.

I don't get the meaning of the line `AND date(order_date) = curdate()`. It seems to be right only if you want today's sales.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem!